# Do any of the major factions use "Carriers"?

Tags: star-trek

In the Star Trek universe we do see usage of "attack wings" (as shown in many of DS9's episodes) and by Starfleet.

However are these attack wings actually housed on larger carriers or are they independent ships capable of warp?

Furthermore does anyone know of any cannon usage of carriers as a regular part of the military (I wouldn't personally count the usage of a shuttle or two as having attack ships) by the Federation or other factions such as the Klingons or Romulans (in the example of the Romulans the scimitar wouldn't count as it was only built once and not a regular vessel type -- as far as I know)

Also I know some games such as STO use carriers but I would prefer evidence from books or screen.

Comment: Thought this might be of interest to you; https://twitter.com/CurtisJobling/status/1343928840943521793

Answer (score 2):

The idea of an aircraft carrier only works if your "planes" are much faster than your "ships" and are able to dodge defensive fire.  Also, the "planes" need to be able to penetrate the defensive "armor".

In the Trek movies, there is little to no indication that small ships can go faster than regular vessels, or that weapons needed to penetrate a shielded ship can be put on a tiny platform.  The capital ships only have a few phaser banks or torpedo tubes (since they all go out at once) so presumably a ship with the engines and size of the Enterprise is needed to power them.  Thus it is unlikely to be mounted on a small "aircraft" like ship.

Comment: Almost every ship has shuttlecraft, and "swarm tactics" are a reasonable approach to space battles, so it's not like it's useless.

Comment: Swarm tactics are **not** a reasonable tactic if you can't damage the craft you are attacking due to its shields.